How to make a formula with correct difference between dates in months?
So I need a formula field to print a difference in months between 2 dates, and it has to be precise to 2 decimals.
So, my variant is:
(EndDate__c -EffectiveDate__c) / 30.5

or, with the other variant is like:
(EndDate__c -EffectiveDate__c) / (365/12)

and I may be okay to live with the technical fault, as the max difference will be 72 month, but am woundering if there's a better, more precise way to calculate this?

Does this answer the question ?

You can use a more precise method by calculating the number of days and then dividing by the average number of days per month.
ROUND(
        ((YEAR(EndDate__c) - YEAR(EffectiveDate__c)) * 12 +
          MONTH(EndDate__c) - MONTH(EffectiveDate__c) -
          IF(DAY(EndDate__c) < DAY(EffectiveDate__c), 1, 0) +
          IF(DAY(EndDate__c) >= DAY(EffectiveDate__c), (DAY(EndDate__c) - DAY(EffectiveDate__c)) / 30.4167, (DAY(EndDate__c) - DAY(EffectiveDate__c) + 30.4167) / 30.4167)),
2
)

The number 30.4167 represents the average number of days per month (365 days / 12 months).
This formula will give you the difference in months between EndDate__c and EffectiveDate__c to two decimal places, using a more accurate average number of days per month.

this formula doesn't work correctly for some reason. for example> if I set effectiveDate  7/03/ 2024 and endDate 7/01/2025 the result shows 0.33, but the result shoud be at least 12~

@SlavaBychenkoCT, I have updated the formula. Please check.
